# No video output booting from Ubuntu 18.04 with dedicated GPU

Tags: boot, 18.04, graphics, video

I have a computer running Ubuntu 18.04 and when it is turned on, all the lights and fans turn on but there is no video output from the graphics card. The specs are as follows:

- AMD Ryzen 2600
- MSI Pro B350 PC Mate
- Crucial MX500 M.2
- G.SKILL Aegis 16GB (2x8GB)
- EVGA 1030

The machine stopped working a few weeks ago. There wasn't any big software or hardware changes that coincided with the onset of this problem. It just booted one day without any video output. The only way I have been able get video is by turning on the computer without any video cables attached and then plugging a DVI cable afterwards. This works only rarely though as most of the attempts will still not give output. I use only one monitor.

At first I thought it may have been software based, so I tried to restore to some older versions of the computer through Clonezilla, but I was still getting no video output. I then thought it may be the graphics card. Since the Ryzen 2600 has no iGPU, I couldn't just remove the 710 card and try, so I purchased a 1030 as the 710 could have died. Unfortunately the 1030 didn't solve the issue. I have also tried re-seating the RAM, M.2 SSD and ensured all power connectors are snug.

I don't know what else I can try and am hoping I can at least get pointed in the proper direction.

Comment: Have you installed the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: For drivers on the 710, I downloaded the recommended open source ones that Ubuntu offered. When I switched to the 1030, I did nothing extra. No pop up came up and I checked the system details to verify drivers and it said I was fine. I do not know the version driver version number.

Comment: Over the past 2 months, I have been taking Clonezilla backups of this machine and another separate machine that is supposed identical. I have tried restoring about 3 images of my machine and 1 image of the other machine. The image is just a full backup of the main drive and I select the 'restoredisk' option to copy over the image. My drive is 500GB and the other machine has 240GB, so there shouldn't be an image size conflict. The backup is kept on an external USB 3.0 drive. The other machine uses an iGPU, not dGPU but is still AMD

Comment: Open Additional Drivers and you should see a list of alternative proprietary Nvidia drivers. By default Ubuntu installs only the open source `nouveau` and it may not work with newer graphics.